# How to add text inside scatter plot using Chart.js?

Tags: javascript, annotations, chart.js, chartjs-2.6.0, chartjs-plugin-zoom

How to render text inside the scatter chart with [Chart.Js](https://www.chartjs.org/). The scatter chart (i'm using) has the [Zoom/pan](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-zoom) plugin, so, i want the text to be anchored to the x/y coordinates of the plot when I'm panning the chart.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [datalabels plugin](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.com/samples/index.html). Although you are saying that you have a `scatter` chart and datalabels does not seem to support this.

Still you could check what you can do with bubble chart, [here is a live example](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.com/samples/charts/bubble.html).

Comment: Kev, Thank you very much for your response. Is it possible to have a custom text on the plot? ex: At point x:40,y:30, can I have a text/text block saying, "This is my positive quadrant"